# Sending http-request with Websocket

Tags: websocket

Trying to send the GET http-request. Here is some code:

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.request({host: 'testapp.com', path: '/cb.php?a=1&b=2', port: 80}, 
  function (data) {
    console.info(data.statusCode)
  }
);
req.end();
```

I can browse url http://testapp.com/cb.php in Chrome, but socket catch timeout error. 
What's the reason?

Comment: there is nothing about web sockets in your code!